# How to build indoor map on Android based off simple floor plan

Tags: android, mapping

I have a simple floor plan of a building as a picture that I want to turn into a *very* simple map on an Android app.

For my specific application, there is no need for navigation or even position detection. I just want a map based off the floor plan that can be scaled / draggable.

I also want to be able to search up specific rooms and have the map highlight that room in a color some way. What would be the best approach to implement such a map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use some open source library, for example, [SVGMapView](https://github.com/jiahuanyu/SVGMapView) to build your map. It can build a map based on SVG image. And if you have another image format - JPG, PNG,etc, you can convert it to SVG at first.
Basically, an idea is in using SVG vector forms (squares, polygons) to define room on the map.

Comment: This looks like something that fits my needs pretty well. I'll make sure to try it out, thanks!

Comment: OK, I`m glad to help